# expected server html to contain a matching a in a

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am getting the following error in my react+next js but I am not sure which page it's coming from.

```
expected server html to contain a matching a in a
Component Stack

a

p

a
```

My guess is from here:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
.....
      <Link href="/" style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', color: "white" }}>
        <div>
          <img src="/logo.png" />
          <span style={{ marginLeft: 10, fontFamily: "cursive" }}>TEST</span>
        </div>
      </Link>
    </LogoContainer>
    <SocialIconsContainer>
      <li>
        <Link href="/" legacyBehavior>
          <StyledLink>Home</StyledLink>
        </Link>
      </li>
...
```

What am i missing out on?

Answer (score 0):

What you're facing is a hydration error. In the code snippet provided above, assuming the `<StyledLink>` is an anchor tag, its nested inside another anchor tag which will lead to hydration error in next.js. You can overcome this error by changing the structure of your code. Or if the `<StyledLink>` is not an anchor tag, please look for places where you're conditionally rendering something based on the values available in localstorage/custom hooks which can also cause UI mismatch thus leading to hydration error since those values won't be available on the server.  [Here are some of the common causes of hydration errors](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error#common-causes)

Comment: Yes styledLink is a ```styled.a` ```.  but how can i change this

Comment: You can change the StyledLink tag to a paragraph StyledP tag and still get the same functionality and it should resolve the error